# Split and sort strings components using Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column in Excel with the format:

A01G45B45D12

I need a way to format it like this, that is divide the string into groups of three characters, sort the groups alphabetically and then join them together with a + sign between:

A01+B45+D12+G45

I wonder it this is possible using the built in formulas in Excel or if I have to do this using VBA or something else, I already have the code for this in C# if there is an easy way to use that from Excel. I have not written plugins for Excel before.

Edit to add:
The above is just an example, the string can be of "any length" but its always divisible by three and the order is random so I cannot assume anything about the order beforehand.

Comment: To get a meaningful answer please read the FAQ with instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and a personal favorite of mine: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried

Comment: Furthermore your initial "problem" is to come up with the logic completely written out. Once you got that done programming shouldnt be the biggest problem, in any language...

Comment: Also your 'group of three' is a group of four items, just to throw some more confusion into the mix.

Comment: I admit the question isn't perfect, and I have written the code for this in C#, its just that I'm not familiar with all the built in functions in Excel and was looking for a way to do it with a formula or something of sorts :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ArraySort()

Dim strStarter As String
Dim strFinish As String
Dim intHowMany As Integer
Dim intStartSlice As Integer

    strStarter = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value 'Pulls value from cell to the left

    intHowMany = Int(Len(strStarter) / 3)
    ReDim arrSlices(1 To intHowMany) As String


    intStartSlice = 1

    For x = 1 To intHowMany

        arrSlices(x) = Mid(strStarter, intStartSlice, 3)

        intStartSlice = intStartSlice + 3

    Next x

    Call BubbleSort(arrSlices)

    For x = 1 To intHowMany

        strFinish = strFinish + arrSlices(x) & "+"

    Next x


strFinish = Left(strFinish, Len(strFinish) - 1)
ActiveCell.Value = strFinish 'Puts result into activecell

End Sub


Sub BubbleSort(list() As String)
'Taken from power programming with VBA
'It’s a sorting procedure for 1-dimensional arrays named List
'The procedure takes each array element, if it is greater than the next element, the two elements swap positions.
'The evaluation is repeated for every pair of items (that is n-1 times)

    Dim First As Integer, Last As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim temp As String
    First = LBound(list)
    Last = UBound(list)

    For i = First To Last - 1
        For j = i + 1 To Last
            If list(i) > list(j) Then
                temp = list(j)
                list(j) = list(i)
                list(i) = temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Im accepting this, since it really answers my question, even though i went with a most excellent library called ExcelDna to be able to reuse my c# code for this and other stuff I also needed to do, bu thank you!